# Find an element in DOM at given position by class

Tags: javascript, html, dom, draggable

I'm trying to make a drag/drop functionality and whilst I'm dragging, I need to find the position relative to a div with a certain class. The problem is that this div is overlapped with the element that I am dragging. In order to get around this, I have a loop that I simply set each element's display style to none and then use elementFromPoint again. So something like this:

```
e = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
while(!e.hasClass("abc")) {
    e.style.display = "none";
    e = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
}
return e;
```

The problem that I'm facing is that I believe when I make the dom element's display style to none, the window shifts up. I would like to avoid that. Is there any other way of going about this?

I'm trying to write the solution with vanilla javascript.

Thanks.

Comment: Erm, `hasClass` is jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, I should mention that I'm using Angular, so that is available to me in jqLite :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can try using

```
e.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

instead of

```
e.style.display = "none";
```

That way the element is hidden from the view, but it still takes up space in the layout. I think that would work for you.

Answer (score 2):

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/oslego/7265412) by **oslego** shows a solution.

```
//
// returns a list of all elements under the cursor
//
function elementsFromPoint(x,y) {
    var elements = [], previousPointerEvents = [], current, i, d;

        // get all elements via elementFromPoint, and remove them from hit-testing in order
    while ((current = document.elementFromPoint(x,y)) && elements.indexOf(current)===-1 && current != null) {

            // push the element and its current style
        elements.push(current);
        previousPointerEvents.push({
                value: current.style.getPropertyValue('pointer-events'),
                priority: current.style.getPropertyPriority('pointer-events')
            });

            // add "pointer-events: none", to get to the underlying element
        current.style.setProperty('pointer-events', 'none', 'important'); 
    }

        // restore the previous pointer-events values
    for(i = previousPointerEvents.length; d=previousPointerEvents[--i]; ) {
        elements[i].style.setProperty('pointer-events', d.value?d.value:'', d.priority); 
    }

        // return our results
    return elements;
}
```

You can either modify that function to do exactly what you want, or search the returned array for an element matching your criteria.

Comment: This works as well, but the solution accepted was more direct. Wish I could accept both!

Comment: It is much simpler; I'd accept that answer if I was you :-)